# lift.default(c) : 'x' should be a formula

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to follow [this code](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/11/searching-for-the-optimal-hyper-parameters-of-an-arima-model-in-parallel-the-tidy-gridsearch-approach/) but this

```
library(tidyverse)
library(forecast)
library(lubridate)
library(furrr)
library(tsibble)
library(brotools)

order_list <- list("p" = seq(0, 3),
       "d" = seq(0, 2),
       "q" = seq(0, 3)) %>%
       cross() %>%
       map(lift(c))
```

Results in:

```
Error in lift.default(c) : 'x' should be a formula
```

Any ideas please? Thanks.

PS:

I think the solution is:

```
purrr::map(lift_dl(c))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution (I think) is using:

```
purrr::map(lift_dl(c))
```